# google earth engine javascript error filteringdate

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

Hello I dont know anything to this but I just have one mistake in my code I dont know why

```
// Load country features from Large Scale International Boundary (LSIB) dataset.
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');
var roi = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_co', 'CB'));
Map.addLayer(roi,{},'Cambodia')

//Let's centre the map view over our ROI
Map.centerObject(roi, 6);

// Filter the collection for the VV product from the descending track
var collectionVV = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'))
    .filterBounds(roi)
    .select(['VV'])
    .median();

// Filter the collection for the VH product from the descending track
var collectionVH = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'))
    .filterBounds(roi)
    .select(['VH'])
    .median();

// Adding the VV layer to the map at a specific date
var image = ee.Image(collectionVV.filterDate('2020-10-14', '2020-10-20').median());
Map.addLayer(image.clip(roi), {min: -25, max: 5}, 'Image_VV');
```

it is for the last line I get :

```
Line 29: collectionVV.filterDate is not a function
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you end your two expressions for `collectionVV` and `collectionVH` with the `.median()` operation, you already reduce both `ImageCollection`s to an image (by taking the median of that collection). Simply removing the `.median()` statements will fix your error. Thus:

```
// Filter the collection for the VH product from the descending track
var collectionVH = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'))
    .filterBounds(roi)
    .select(['VH'])
    //.median();

// Adding the VV layer to the map at a specific date
var image = ee.Image(collectionVH.filterDate('2020-10-14', '2020-10-20').median());
Map.addLayer(image.clip(roi), {min: -25, max: 5}, 'Image_VV');
```